# Extract sheet of paper from photo in Browser/javascript/webgl

Tags: javascript, canvas, computer-vision, glsl

A similar question has been asked before - but the answers involve OpenCV with Python or C++. My use case requires this to happen in a browser environment.

I am trying to identify the 4 corners of a sheet of paper in a photo, in order to then straighten the sides into a rectangle.

Currently my approach is:

- blur and threshold in a shader with WebGL (faked with imagemagick for now, but a known problem)
- calculate x and y differentials also in a shader with WebGL
- identify the convex hull of points with a differential above a threshold using [hull.js](https://github.com/AndriiHeonia/hull)
- ????
- straighten the image with [glfx.js](https://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/)

where ???? is where I get stuck - going from a convex hull to a quadrangular hull - which would then give me the corners to straighten.

The shader for calculating the differential is here:

```
void main(){
    vec2 cellSize = 1.0 / resolution;
    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy );
    
    vec4 color = texture2D(image, position);

    vec2 step = 1.0 / resolution.xy;
    
    vec4 rightCol  = texture2D(image, position + vec2(step.x, 0.0));
    vec4 bottomCol = texture2D(image, position + vec2(0.0, step.y));

    float y = 0.299 * color.r + 0.587 * color.g + 0.114 * color.b;
    color = vec4(y, y, y, 1.0);
    
    y = 0.299 * rightCol.r + 0.587 * rightCol.g + 0.114 * rightCol.b;
    rightCol  = vec4(y, y, y, 1.0);

    y = 0.299 * bottomCol.r + 0.587 * bottomCol.g + 0.114 * bottomCol.b;
    bottomCol  = vec4(y, y, y, 1.0);
    
    float thrs = y < 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    
    float maxColor = length(color.rgb);


    float r = abs(length(-rightCol  + color) / step.x);
    float g = abs(length(-bottomCol + color) / step.y);

    
    // gl_FragColor.r = r;
    // gl_FragColor.g = g;

    gl_FragColor.r = abs(dFdx(maxColor));
    gl_FragColor.g = abs(dFdy(maxColor));

    
    gl_FragColor.b = 0.0;
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

These is an example of the images I am trying to process and the steps.

**source (blurred for privacy)**

[image]

**blur and threshold**

[image]

**differential**

[image]

**convex hull**

[image]

Now I am thinking of a brute force, combinatoric approach, trying out all groups of 4 points until I find the largest rectangle.

I've also tried Harris corner detection with [the FivekoGFX library](https://fiveko.com/feature-points-using-harris-corner-detector/) but I got too many false positives for it to be useful.

What would be a way to solve the "find the quadrangle" problem? is there anything better than brute force? any pointers to libraries or algorithms would be helpful.

Comment: Find the min and max limits in both x and y (bounding box). Then for those limits search along the row or column until you get to non-background pixel in the binary mask.

Comment: I do the above in an Imagemagick shell script to find the corners, thto unrotate an image via an affine or rigid affine transformation. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/unrotate3/index.php